# Problems with relative and absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, css-position

Im having some issues achieving absolute positioning on an element.  Im trying to implement two banner ads to stay stationary when the user scrolls through a div.  I tried changing the parents position to relative and the children I want to remain static position to absolute.  This gets the initial placement right, but I am still able to scroll past the absolute divs.  Here is the appropriate CSS/HTML.

HTML:

```
<div id="pane1">


  <div id="home-banner1" class="banner">

  </div>

  <div id="home-banner2" class="banner">

  </div>

  <?php .....  ?>


</div>
```

CSS:

```
#pane1{
width:100%;
background-repeat: repeat;
height:auto;
display:inline-block;
padding:20px 50px 50px 50px;
min-height:500px;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
}

.banner{
width:50px;
height:300px;
background-color:white;
position:absolute;
top:0;
}

#home-banner1{
left:0;
}

#home-banner2{
right:0;
}
```

Comment: Try position:Sticky.  here is the link to MDN for your reference. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `position:fixed;` for the banners so that it will stay on screen at fixed location even while you scroll up or down the page.

**EDIT**

For the hiding and displaying of banner only below that `#container` element, you could use some jQuery like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var top_div_height = $('#container').height(); // height of the blue top container

    if ($(this).scrollTop() < top_div_height) {  // hide the rightside banner if the user is viewing that blue top container
        $('#home-banner2').css({
            'display': 'none'
        });
    }
    else{  //... otherwise show the rightside banner
        $('#home-banner2').css({
            'display': 'block'
        });
    }
});
```

Make sure you set the CSS rule `position:fixed;` for the `#home-banner2` element.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi Akhilesh, I tried that but it fixes the banners to the top of the DOM rather than to the 'pane1' div.

Comment: Thank you, that is just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code work exactly as expected.

`Position: absolute` move the element relative to the closest parent element with `position: relative`. So, if the parent element go outside the viewport, so it does the child absolute element.

To get the wanted result, you need some javascript/jquery to fix the element as its parent enter the viewport and 'unfix' when the parent leaves.

Something similar to the [Bootstraps' affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix)